# Segregate ODD and EVEN numbers in an Array using C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am barely new to programming, I need to sort an array of integers by having all the odd numbers on the left side and even numbers on the right side by calling a function.

This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

void sortOdd(int arr[], int size) {
int odd = 0;
int even = size - 1;

while (even > odd) {
  int temp;

  while(arr[odd] % 2 != 0) {
    odd++;
  }
  while(arr[even] % 2 == 0) {
    even--;
  }

  temp = arr[odd];
  arr[odd] = arr[even];
  arr[even] = temp;
  odd++;
  even--;
}
}

int main () {

int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);


cout << "unsorted array" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << arr[i] << " ";

sortOdd(arr, size);

cout << "sorted array" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << arr[i] << " ";


  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it only sorts/swaps the outer elements and not the middle ones, and it outputs something like this:

```
unsorted array
1 2 3 4 5 6
sorted array
1 5 4 3 2 6
```

Can someone help what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: `std::partition`.  That is function you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) like this:

```
std::partition(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](int a) {
    return a % 2;
});
```

Comment: The algorithm HaZa is attempting to implement is O(n), while this would be O(n log n).

Comment: @pjs -- The `std::partition` is not `O(n log n)`.  It is `O(n)`.   This should be the accepted answer, unless the OP is doing this for a school exercise and needs to implement it from scratch.

Comment: @FredLarson Hmm... I thought it was transitivity the one that failed, but it actually held, because there is no way you can find a < b and b < c such that a < c, because as soon as you have a < b, then you cannot find any c such that b < c, so it is trivially true (only 2 equivalence classes). So I think it was a valid strict weak ordering (although anyway it is of course better and simpler to use `std::partition`).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Got it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change your while condition to this:

```
while (even > odd+1)
```

Your algorithm works for the most part but you took one extra iteration and it swaps your your the middle values.